# Squid Proxy access_log

Tags: proxy, squid, access-log

I have successfully run SQUID Proxy. My question is, why does my logs showing a date if 2002** (ex. 20020403.gz) ? When I have just installed SQUID Proxy 2months ago.. so it should show something like 2014** (ex. 20140114.gz).

Please help. Thanks!

```
[root@localhost squid]# ls -al
total 243692

drwxr-x---.  2 squid squid      4096 May 26 03:34 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root  root       4096 May 27 08:53 ..
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid 135516255 May 28 05:10 access.log
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid       909 Apr 30 03:48 access.log-20020430.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid   4969264 May  5 03:08 access.log-20020505.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid  20266554 May 12 03:21 access.log-20020512.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid  35496750 May 19 03:27 access.log-20020519.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid  52738398 May 26 03:34 access.log-20020526.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid    207707 May 28 05:08 cache.log
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid     52161 May  5 03:08 cache.log-20020505.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid     26572 May 12 03:21 cache.log-20020512.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid     45306 May 19 03:27 cache.log-20020519.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid     50880 May 26 03:34 cache.log-20020526.gz
-rw-r-----.  1 squid squid      2743 Oct 20  2013 cache.log-20131020.gz
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     118299 May 28 05:08 squid.out
```

Comment: Please show the output of the command:  date -Iseconds on the server in question.

Comment: I am on CentOS6.. _date -lseconds_ does not seem to work.

Comment: The character after the - is a capital i, not a lowercase L.

Comment: @Slartibartfast - You seem to figure it out : date -Iseconds
_2002-05-28T06:29:40+0800_

Comment: How to resolve this? and change it to the proper date?

Comment: @upbeta01: Can you use ntpdate by update your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work out why the system is being set with the incorrect date, and, having worked that out, mitigate the issue.

For a date like 2002, I'm going to guess dead BIOS battery on the server hardware.

One possible mitigation for slightly inaccurate time is to use NTP to synchronize the time to a good time source.  You want to be careful to use NTP at the ideal layer if you are using virtualization technology.  Typically you want to synchronize the time at the lowest possible layer (e.g. the virtualization software) to ensure the most consistency and best performance.

As such, if you are using virtualization software, see if you can configure it to synchronize the time to a network time server.  Otherwise, look into setting up an NTP client for your chosen platform.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise. However, as I have checked my ntp.conf it got this..


_# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org_

Comment: Does this mean that the time on centos.pool.ntp.org is not working properly?

Comment: Nope.  It may simply mean that your NTP server is set correctly to quit rather than "step" the clock on boot if it is too wrong.  The solution is to fix the source of incorrect time; NTP should be a fine tuning measure.